# What kind of data structure should I use for Bellman-Ford algorithm?

Tags: php, arrays, list, data-structures, bellman-ford

I have to apply **Bellman-Ford algorithm** in **shortest path problem problem**  for foreign exchange rates. I'm using PHP. At first I thought that I will process the data in a form of array. But then I realized that using array isn't a great choice of data structure , since I'm getting the data from API (return in json type).

Anyone can give me some ideas about **structuring the data**? (I will use the rates,  money's symbol, etc).
Here's my code to process the data getting (preprocessing->I choose to use array, before jump into bellman-ford algorithm):

```
$rates = json_decode($data);
$arraydata = array();
foreach ($rates->rates as $key => $value)
{
    //1. USD to another currency
    $arraytmp = array();
    array_push($arraytmp, $rates->base, $key, $value);
    array_push($arraydata, $arraytmp);

    //2. another currency to USD
    $arraytmp = array();
    $nilai = 1 / $value;
    array_push($arraytmp, $key, $rates->base, round($nilai, 5));
    array_push($arraydata, $arraytmp);
}
```

But then, I dont know how I can get the exchange rate between another currencies (for example CAD to SGD). I mean, I know how to do that MANUALLY. But number of the currency is 166. Of course, we dont want to do that manually. 
**Or, do I choose the wrong data structure?**
Here's the data in JSON :

```
{
  base : "USD",
  rates :
  {
    "AED": 3.67286,
    "AFN": 57.12,
    "ALL": 101.2193,
    "AMD": 416.650001,
    "ANG": 1.78898,
    ...
  }
}
```

And I also want to describe the data into a **graph**, should I keep use array?

Comment: Can you give a little more information about the data description of what is arriving in the json?  Also can you spell out the nature of your queries into this data?  There are many, many types of data structures in the world, and the first question I always ask, is what are the questions that will be asked of the data.

Comment: This sounds like homework.